# AWS - Adding multiple IPs to Security Group Inbound Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, security-groups

I need to open 20 ports for 12 IP blocks.

Do I have to manually add 240 rules in this case? I feel like there must be a way to just copy&paste the IP list to somewhere.

I googled and found it's not possible, but it's hard to believe.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=191133

Comment: You'd probably want to script against the AWS CLI: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP Lists are supported in WAF, but using that would probably add a bunch of complexity that you don't want/need right now. They can't be used directly in front of an instance and need something like a load balancer or CloudFront distribution.

If you can't use IP ranges (subnets) to reduce the number of rules my recommendation would be to use the CLI to create/manage the rules you need. You can manually run the commands OR write a script to read the info from somewhere (like a text file).

The AWS CLI is available for most environments. PowerShell Tools for AWS is also decent if you prefer PowerShell though I have found a few limitations that the CLI does not have.

One thing to verify is if a security group can contain 240 rules (check the limits). You might need to spread this across a few security groups.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I've searched, the best way to manage this problem is to use prefix list.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/managed-prefix-lists.html

Comment: I tried it, every item in the list is counted towards the limit so this doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

A bit late here, but a way to do it faster is to create multiple rules, one for each IP block, and create the other rules using the `Copy to a new security group` option, this way you don't need to write the rules each time, just copy and paste the IP addresses.

[image]

I know that using CLI is much faster and repeatable but this can be a quick fix since it is much easier and not everyone knows how to do it with the CLI :)